# Mensaje Flash por Ajax Rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails

Estoy intentando mostrar un mensaje Flash por Ajax, ya que poseo un modal que al cerrarse deseo notifique al usuario que la acción se realizo, utilizo Foundation 6, y lastimosamente a esta versión aun le falta que se le agreguen cosas fundamentales como los mensajes "Toast" de Materialize, LightBox, ya que solo están en la versión 5, regresando al punto, no logro obtener el mensaje después de realizar la acción, a continuación mi código:

**layouts/_alert.html.erb**

```
<% if notice %>
  <div class="callout small notice">
    <%= notice %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<% if alert %>
  <div class="callout small alert">
    <%= alert %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="callout">
  <h6>Formulario de contacto</h6>

  <%= form_for @contact, remote: true, authenticity_token: true do |f| %>
    <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
      <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@contact.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this @contact from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
        <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_field :title, placeholder: "Titulo del mensaje" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Contenido del mensaje", :rows => 10, :cols => 120 %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Enviar mensaje", class: "button" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

**create.js.erb**

```
<% if @home.errors.empty? %>
  $('#exampleModal1').foundation('close');
  $(".notice").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts" %>');
<% else %>
  $(".alert").html('<%= j render partial: "layouts/alerts" %>');
<% end %>
```

**contact_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
    @contact.email = current_enterprise.email

    respond_to do |format|
      if @contact.save
        ContactMailer.contact_email(@contact).deliver
        format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Contact was successfully created.' }
        format.js { flash[:notice] = "El mensaje ha sido enviado" }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @contacts }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: alguna ves leí que las llamadas por ajax no pasan el mensaje flash. Lo que yo hago generalmente es agregar los campos necesarios en la respuesta ajax para mostrar mensajes. Generalmente agrego `status` y `mensaje`, así según `status` muestro o no el `mensaje`

Comment: No se si tenga que ver, pero ¿y si mejor mueves el `flash[:notice]` fuera de `format.js`? así además te ahorras el tener que definir `notice` en `format.html` ¿Y si usas `flash.now[:notice]`? ¿Has probado a hacer un `<% puts flash.inspect %>` dentro de `layouts/_alert.html.erb` para ver si efectivamente trae el mensaje?.  
Respecto a lo que dice @inye, eso no es así, ya que anteriormente he agregado información flash dentro de un template `js.erb` y no me ha dado problemas.

Comment: Fijense que es curioso, pero como si fuese capaz de mostrarlo por ajax, lo que sucede es que realizo la accion y el modal se cierra pero no me da mensaje, asique recargo la pagina y ahi si muestra el mensaje